# Flex ComboBox user choice reset

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

To be more descriptive here's a live example:
http://interklub.biz/CTPonLine.html

In last column there's a ComboBox with some values.
When user choose an option in ComboBox from first row and then scroll down the first choice disapears (comes back to default state).
There's something more strange, earlier I've tried to apply a one more ComboBox in additional column, with highly dynamic values (completly different for different rows), but with after same action (scroll down and then scroll down) values dataProviders from different ComboBox were switch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not initializing your item renderer properly--when the renderer is reused, it's keeping its old value rather than updating from your data.

You should be able to resolve this by doing one of the following:

1. binding the item renderer's `selectedValue` to some property of its `data` element

   - overriding `set data()` to update the control for the current data
   - acting on the dataChange event and updating there

See Adobe's [Working with Item Renderers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_8.html) for more.